# Substring Function don't work with a variable

Tags: powershell, directory, substring, get-childitem

I need the first 3 bytes of a string.  My code gets an error.

```
# This Code don't work
$folderoutput="Z:\Home\Chronos\" + $datum.Month;
$test = Get-ChildItem -Path $folderinput| select name, state -last 1
$test.Substring(0,3)

# This Code work
$folderoutput="Z:\Home\Chronos\" + "11"
$test = Get-ChildItem -Path $folderinput| select name, state -last 1
$test.Substring(0,3)
```

**Error:**

> Method invocation failed because [Selected.System.IO.FileInfo] does
>   not contain a method named 'Substring'. At Z:\skript\uebung1.ps1:16
>   char:1
>   + $test.Substring(0,3)
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Substring:String) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

What is the reason for the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `$test` variable references not a `String` but an object composed from the `Name` and `State` properties of the returned [`FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo) instance.  There is no [`Substring` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?#System_String_Substring_System_Int32_System_Int32_) on this composed object (nor on a `FileInfo`, for that matter), hence the error.  To get the name of the file you need to access the [`Name` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo.name), like so...

```
$test.Name.Substring(0, 3)
```

Alternatively, if you only want the `Name` property (not sure where `State` comes from) you could use the [`-ExpandProperty` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object#optional-parameters) to retrieve only that one value...

```
$test = Get-ChildItem -Path $folderinput| select -ExpandProperty name -last 1
$test.Substring(0, 3)
```

As for why one snippet works and the other doesn't, that's unclear.  The only difference between the two is the value of `$folderoutput`, which is not used; on the following line you pass `$folderinput` to `Get-ChildItem`.  Are you sure `$datum` is set and has a `Month` property?

Comment: Thank you for your Feedback.
$folderinput is wrong. Only $folderinput is correct.

The Use Case is:
Subfolders from 1 (January) to 12 (December).

Comment: Thank you for your Feedback.
$folderinput is wrong. Only $folderinput is correct.

The Use Case is:
Subfolders named from 1 (January) to 12 (December).
Depend from the month i save the file to folder 1 or 2 or 3 etc.

My Plan is to write the month (1 to 12) as string in a variable. Then i take the Path ""Z:\Home\Chronos\" and add the month (1 or 2 or etc.)

Comment: I'm not clear on whether or not my code suggestions solved or helped with your issue.  Also, the code comments in your question say the second snippet works but the first does not.  So only the first snippet throws the listed error?  It seems like they both should because, as I mentioned, they're both so similar.  It would be helpful if you update the question with these additional details and variable corrections.

Comment: I understand what you say, about FSO and not a string.
I need only a solution, to catch the month with numbers, then i use as a string.

I try tostring. But the result is not was i want. Get-Date with to string ("m") don't give me the number from  the month.

Comment: The only further advice I can offer with the information provided is that if `$datum` contains a `DateTime` (e.g. `$datum = Get-Date`, `$datum = [DateTime]::Today)` then `$datum.Month` is the correct way to access the month component.  However, you don't show how `$datum` is set.  I think you really need to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question because there are too many unknowns here to do anything but guess.  The problem you describe in these comments seems to be different than the one in the question, as well.